# Design: how to store lots of booleans?

Tags: database-design

What is the most optimal way to store lots (up to 300) of properties about an object? All properties determinate presence of a factor. Like, "has dog", "has cat", "has garden", "has *N*".

Initially I was thinking about a table with 300 columns:

```
create table my_objects (
    has_dog enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
    has_cat enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
    has_garden enum('0','1') NOT NULL
);
```

Don't bother the relevance of the `enum` type, it's there only for extra self-explanatory reasons.

But having those `has_` x 300 columns makes my guts feel nervous.

Any advice is much appreciated.

### EDIT

Since many people started asking correct questions, here's the additional info:

- The db will mostly exclusively handle `SELECT` queries. Selects consist of combination of `has_{prop} = 0|1 AND/OR has_{prop} = 0|1`. Like heavy filtering.
- There will be Sphinx/Solr layer on top of db.
- The amount of properties is constant. So if there's one row in table `my_objects`, it will have those 300 columns filled, either with default values, or defined.
- `my_objcets` table will hold no more than 1 mil of objects.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What type of queries do you need to do against this data?

Comment: And why use enum? Most DBMS have a boolean or bit datatype.

Comment: @MartinSmith, MySQL, Postgre. One of those. 99% of queries are `SELECT`-s with mixture of AND/OR specifiers  for those 300 `has_cat = 1`, `has_garden = 0`.

Comment: @ypercube yes, I won't be using `enum`, like I said, it wanted it there just to make my requirements more clear.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, always the same number of properties.

Answer (score 1):

"Just" 300? That might not really be a problem, actually. How many rows do you expect in the table? If not that many, say, less than a million, then doing that might not be a huge problem.

Or if you're using PostgreSQL, as noted, you can use an array of booleans. That, I think, would be preferrable to putting each column individually in the schema.

The "best" way, however, would be a bitfield. Say, an array of a hundred 4-byte integers, with each value being one of the bits in one of those fields.  So your application could have a map of tupes, something like:

```
has["dog"] = (25, 18)
```

Noting that 'dog' would be in the 26th field (zero based), in the 19th bit. When you want to query if a record has a dog, you'd need to pull the appropriate tuple and construct an SQL statement like...

```
(fieldNum, bitNum) = has["dog"] # python syntax

SELECt * from tbl WHERE (has[fieldNum] & (1<<bitNum)) > 0
```

Finally, Postgres also has bit strings, which I've never used, but it looks like they might do the job as well. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/datatype-bit.html

Comment: This is actually very interesting. Thx. I was thinking about serialising combination of properties into some kind of a hash, and store it as well. But bitfield is something worth trying out.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal way to handle it is to table-drive the things.  If you have 300 of them now, what are the chances that you're going to have 301 tomorrow?  Instead of making frequent schema changes, just keep a table of `OWNABLE_THINGS` and use a *many-to-many* relationship to track which things your objects own.

Here are both the conceptual view, and the logical view, which uses an *intersection table* to persist the many-to-many relationship values.

[image: ERD]

In this approach you can simply have a record for each thing which an object has.  That way, if an object only has 10 of 300 things, you only need 10 records in your intersection table.  That's less data to manage.

Alternatively, if you really, really want to have and maintain 300 data points for each object, you can have a fully populated intersection table and add your `has_one` bit field to this table.

Comment: But I suppose that will force me to do (up to) 300 joins, whenever my `SELECT` goes fancy with dozens of `has_dog=1 AND has_cat=0 OR has_garden=1`? I'm now trying to evaluate the performance impact over the single table with 300 columns. Although it might not be that problematic, cos I'll put Solr/Sphinx on top of db. The frequent change should not be an issue. One more thing worth noting is that whenever object is created it will have those 300 properties.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov - If one of your major use cases is searching by a list of particular types of things that your object has, then using 300 bit columns will inevitably result in table scans, so your query performance will _has tortoise_ as it were.  Depending on how many of your ownable things a typical object has (i.e. if the average number is much less than 300) then you are probably better off using the pure intersection rather than a fully populated intersection with a bit flag.  Treat the absence of a link record as "not owned".  This will be at least as performant as 300 bit flags.

Comment: what do you call "pure intersection"? A column intersecting a row?

Comment: @AleksandrMakov - A "pure intersection" is a table containing only foreign keys that together make a composite primary key for the table.  `OBJECT_HAS_THING` would be a _pure intersection_ if the only columns in that table are `my_object_id` and `ownable_thing_id` and if both of these columns together are the primary key of the table.  If you added a third column to this table, say `has_one` (bit) then it would no longer be a pure intersection.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Give me couple of days, I'll make up a sandboxed db and report.